# ARCore session is not restarting

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

Using Google ARCore, when I am in the game I have built I have a restart button to clear the scene and restart the level. I was doing this by reloading the scene using `Scenemanager.LoadScene()`, however when the scene reloads the camera is not initialised and just shows a blue screen with my UI over the top.

Is there something I can use in code to ensure this doesn't happen when reloading the scene?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your Android console?

Comment: I am also facing same issue as asked in question. How can i get around it ? Any Help.....

Comment: This seems to have been resolved in the ARCore developer preview 2. Are you using the latest version of the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

**In ARCore NDK** you'd use the following method for destroying a session and releasing its resources:

```
void ArSession_destroy(
    ArSession *session
)
```

This method releases resources used by an ARCore session. It'll take several seconds to complete. To prevent blocking the main thread, call `ArSession_pause()` on the **main thread**, and then call `ArSession_destroy()` on a **background thread**.

**Then, you have to create a new session with :**

```
ArSession_create()
```

Also, **in ARCore Android**, there's typically `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods for **current session**. But I use 2 other ones: `pause()` for pausing the current session and `resume()` for starting or resuming the ARCore current session.

**In Unity** you should try `DestroyImmediate(session)` or `Destroy(session)` for your purpose.

```
ARCoreSession session = goARCoreDevice.GetComponent<ARCoreSession>();
ARCoreSessionConfig myConfig = session.SessionConfig;
DestroyImmediate(session);
// Destroy(session);
yield return null;
session = goARCoreDevice.AddComponent<ARCoreSession>();
session.SessionConfig = myConfig;
session.enabled = true;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and help! The ArSession class exists into NDK only? Not in Android ArCore library? (screenshot http://prntscr.com/lk5vzs ). I don't use NDK for my task.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, this session's management is for NDK (it's documented though). I do not know exactly if session's management exists for ARCore Lib. Maybe `YES`, maybe `NO`. There's no Google description on this issue...

Comment: Ok, thank you! I just will try to recreate the ArFragment.

Comment: You're welcome! If you succeed in destroying a session via ARCore Lib, please let me know about it.

Comment: Sir, can you help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437128/how-i-can-set-repeated-texture-on-an-object-in-android-arcore-sceneform-api

Comment: Hi @AndrewGrow, how you recreated the ArFragment?

Comment: @NoumanCh Hello. In finally, we have went to other way ) Close activity - open other activity.

Comment: hmm this is not good for UX. I'm replacing a fragment and it's working for me. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For those who have an issue with ARCore in android studio, to solve this I used the simple workaround of replacing fragment instead of restarting entire Activity.

**Procedure:** I'm adding ArFragment dynamically and when the user press on refresh button I'm replacing the entire fragment.

1-Adding Fragment dynamically:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainARFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

2-Here is my refresh button code:

```
 refreshButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            //refresh everything remove models and detect from start
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new MainARFragment()).commit();
        });
```

Everything worked fine but when I tried to findFragmentById after adding it inside onCreate method I got null pointer exception. To avoid this use Callback from ArFragment and in onAttach of ArFragment call the onComplete method and then use :

```
arFragment = (MainARFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
```

Hope this will help.