# (Sceneform)How to user texture, using .mat file

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am from a non-English speaking country, so I am not familiar with English. Thank you for your understanding.

I was rendering the dash line based on this link. BUT, Even after two days, it is still not being resolved at all.
[How I can set repeated texture on an object in Android ArCore Sceneform API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437128/how-i-can-set-repeated-texture-on-an-object-in-android-arcore-sceneform-api)

As you can see, the object is completely black.
I guess, this code doesn't seem to load any textures at all! I must have made a mistake in my understanding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH9yh.jpg)

Please help me if my question doesn't violate community rules.

My base fake modeling is .gltf file. Use Blender v2.8
How I attach texture that custom material file? This is my code.

-line.gltf

```
{
"asset" : {
    "generator" : "Khronos glTF Blender I/O v1.5.17",
    "version" : "2.0"
},
"scene" : 0,
"scenes" : [
    {
        "name" : "Scene",
        "nodes" : [
            0
        ]
    }
],
"nodes" : [
    {
        "mesh" : 0,
        "name" : "Plane",
        "rotation" : [
            0.7071068286895752,
            0,
            0,
            0.7071067094802856
        ]
    }
],
"materials" : [
    {
        "doubleSided" : true,
        "name" : "None",
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorFactor" : [
                0.800000011920929,
                0.800000011920929,
                0.800000011920929,
                1
            ],
            "metallicFactor" : 0,
            "roughnessFactor" : 0.5
        }
    }
],
"meshes" : [
    {
        "name" : "Plane",
        "primitives" : [
            {
                "attributes" : {
                    "POSITION" : 0,
                    "NORMAL" : 1,
                    "TEXCOORD_0" : 2
                },
                "indices" : 3,
                "material" : 0
            }
        ]
    }
],
"accessors" : [
    {
        "bufferView" : 0,
        "componentType" : 5126,
        "count" : 4,
        "max" : [
            0.5,
            0,
            0.5
        ],
        "min" : [
            -0.5,
            0,
            -0.5
        ],
        "type" : "VEC3"
    },
    {
        "bufferView" : 1,
        "componentType" : 5126,
        "count" : 4,
        "type" : "VEC3"
    },
    {
        "bufferView" : 2,
        "componentType" : 5126,
        "count" : 4,
        "type" : "VEC2"
    },
    {
        "bufferView" : 3,
        "componentType" : 5123,
        "count" : 6,
        "type" : "SCALAR"
    }
],
"bufferViews" : [
    {
        "buffer" : 0,
        "byteLength" : 48,
        "byteOffset" : 0
    },
    {
        "buffer" : 0,
        "byteLength" : 48,
        "byteOffset" : 48
    },
    {
        "buffer" : 0,
        "byteLength" : 32,
        "byteOffset" : 96
    },
    {
        "buffer" : 0,
        "byteLength" : 12,
        "byteOffset" : 128
    }
],
"buffers" : [
    {
        "byteLength" : 140,
        "uri" : "line.bin"
    }
]
```

}

My bin file is separate.

- repeating_texture.mat

  material {
  "name" : "RepeatingTexture",
  parameters : [
  {
  type : sampler2d,
  name : texture
  },

  ```
    {
        type: "float",
        name:"repeat_x"
    },
    {
            type: "float",
            name: "repeat_y"
    }
   ],
   requires : [
       "position",
       "uv0"
   ],
  ```

  }
  fragment {
  void material(inout MaterialInputs material) {
  prepareMaterial(material);

  ```
        vec2 uv = getUV0();
        uv.x = uv.x * materialParams.repeat_x;
        uv.y = uv.y * materialParams.repeat_y;

        material.baseColor = texture(materialParams_texture, uv).rgba;


    }
  ```

  }

this is model rendering method.
I call this method from main activity, onCreate().

```
        ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(context, com.mary.myapplication.R.raw.material_holder)
        .build()
        .thenAccept(Consumer { modelRenderable: ModelRenderable ->
            repeatingMaterial = modelRenderable.material
            DlogUtil.d(TAG, "해치웠나? ㅇㅇ")
            EventCenter.instance.sendEvent(ESSArrow.LOAD_MODELIING_FINISH, this, null)
        }).exceptionally {
            DlogUtil.d(TAG, "해치웠나? ㄴㄴ")

            return@exceptionally null
        }
```

This is rendering method.

```
    fun drawDashCylinderLine(
    context: Context,
    lineColor: Color,
    radius: Float,
    length: Float,
    parentNode: TransformableNode,
    from: Vector3,
    to: Vector3
) {

    val lengthCM: Float = length * 100

    repeatingMaterial?.setFloat("repeat_x", lengthCM / 10)
    repeatingMaterial?.setFloat("repeat_y", lengthCM / 10)

    MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(context, lineColor)
        .thenAccept { material: Material? ->
            // 2. make a model by the material
            val model = ShapeFactory.makeCylinder(
                radius, length,
                Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), repeatingMaterial
            )

            // 3. make node
            val node = Node()
            node.renderable = model

            node.setParent(parentNode)
            node.worldPosition = Vector3.add(to, from).scaled(.5f);

            //4. set rotation
            val difference = Vector3.subtract(to, from)
            val directionFromTopToBottom = difference.normalized()
            val rotationFromAToB =
                Quaternion.lookRotation(
                    directionFromTopToBottom,
                    Vector3.up()
                )
            node.worldRotation = Quaternion.multiply(
                rotationFromAToB,
                Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 90f)
            )
        }
}
```

Here is my texture file location....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfAxL.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a temporary fix, but I've found a solution!

When calling the modelRenderable from onCreate(), the texture was also called and specified as a global variable.

```
        Texture.builder().setSource { context.assets.open("textures/line_texture.png") }
        .setSampler(sampler)
        .build()
        .thenAccept {
            texture = it
        }
```

However, unfortunately, the material's transparency was not applied. If anyone knows how to apply it, give me an answer (crying)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw4Ft.jpg)

I need control Opacity.......!

Answer (score 0):

This was too easy a problem if I had read the docs carefully.
This was a configuration issue in the .mat file.

add this material reference

```
blending : transparent
```